# Call method from Java in R gives missing method error

Tags: r, methods, double, signature, rjava

I want to use R to optimize some parameters. Therefore I have a java method:

```
run(double hw, doubl sw, double no){...; return someDouble)
```

Now I wanted to call this from R using:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit(someJar, "-jar")
.jaddClasspath("My\\Class\\Path")
mainR <- function(params, tmpfile=tmpfile()){
     obj <- .jnew("Helper/ROptimzer")
     c <- .jcall(obj, returnSig = "D", "run", params[1], params[2], params[3])
     return(c)
}
params = c(1,2,3)
res <- optim(param, mainR, NULL, method="BFGS")
```

From this I get the following error message:

```
Error in .jcall(obj, returnSig = "D", "run", params[1],  : method run with signature (DDD)D not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I changed Java my JDK in the IDE to have the same Patch and Bit version than the one in rJava (1.7.0_79 x64) I was able to start a simple Systemcommand running the application inside R but i am still not able to get .jpackage or .jinit to load the whole jar file into JVM.

**EDIT2:**
I was able to load the JAR file into the JVM.
This is my current code:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_79\\jre")
library(rJava)
#.jaddClassPath("C:\\Users\\***\\artifacts")
.jinit("C:\\Users\\***\\xyz.jar","*")

print(.jclassPath())
obj <- .jnew("Helper/Optimizer")
.jmethods(obj)

mainR<-function(params)
{
  c <- J(obj,returnSig = "D","optimR",params[1], params[2], params[3])
  return(c)
}
param = c(1125,15,5)
res <- optim(param, mainR, NULL, method="BFGS")
print(res)
```

And

```
public double optimR(double hw, double sw, double no) {
        try {

            return someVeryLongRunningFunction((int)hw, (int)sw,(int) no);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the
>   given parameters Called from: .jcheck(silent = FALSE)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Okay .jmethods gave me as result that it expects run() to be without return value even though I rebuild the project. After renaming and rebuilding the class it still shows me run() as the only method to call. NOTE: Its not derived from object!

Comment: This is just plain crazy. Now i closes RStudio to get rid of any leftovers whatsoever and now it doenst find the class, while i didnt change ANYTHING expect closing and opening rstudio

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this structure

```
.
├── sample
│   └── DoubleCall.java
└── target
    └── sample
        └── DoubleCall.class
```

and you compile following code

```
package sample;

public class DoubleCall {
  public double optimR(double hw, double sw, double no) {
    try {
      return someVeryLongRunningFunction((int)hw, (int)sw,(int) no);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return 0.0;
    }
  }

  private double someVeryLongRunningFunction(int hw, int sw, int no) {
    return 2.0;
  }

  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    DoubleCall dc = new DoubleCall();
    System.out.println("Result: " + dc.optimR(1.0, 1.1, 1.2));
  }
}
```

Then, you can compile and test it following way

```
> javac -d target sample/*.java
> java -cp target sample.DoubleCall
```

Once it works fine, you can export CLASSPATH and start R

```
> export CLASSPATH=`pwd`/target
> R
```

Then, you can play with rJava

```
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
> obj <- .jnew("sample.DoubleCall")
> s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="D", method="optimR", 1.0, 1.1, 1.2)
> print(s)
> [1] 2
```

It should work.